# Redirect Google cloud ftp server to http server

Tags: http, server, ftp, cloud

we need to redirect a google cloud `ftp` server to http server for client. I have researched and it seem impossible to redirect at `ftp`.

Would it possible to redirect by changing firewall setting at `ftp` server to `http`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Though it's not possible to redirect FTP to HTTP. It does not matter where/how you want to redirect it.